# [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:0A000102:SSL routines::unsupported protocol]

Tags: python, sql-server, odbc

I'm encountering an issue while trying to connect to a SQL Server database using Python on macOS with Brew. I'm receiving the following error message:

> conn = Database.connect(connstr, **args)
> django.db.utils.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:0A000102:SSL routines::unsupported protocol] (-1) (SQLDriverConnect)')

I can ping the database server and I was able to connect to the database using the Azure Data Studio, so I know that the network connectivity and database access credentials are correct but still can't connect my application.

I tried specify openSSL version for ODBC Driver, since I have both openssl@3 and openssl@1.1 but none works.

I still tried to use `Encrypt=false;TrustServerCertificate=true` to disable encryption and ignore server certificate errors, but doesn't work too.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: post your sanitized code

Comment: Does the target server have the "Force Encryption" option enabled (e.g.: SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for MSSQLServer > Properties > Force Encryption)? That will require clients to connect with encryption even when their connection string includes `Encrypt=False;`.

Comment: Since you can connect from ADS, what's the output of `SELECT @@VERSION` on the target server? Older versions before SQL Server 2016 did not have TLS 1.2 support out-of-the-box (it could be added with Service Packs and Cumulative Updates, ref: [TLS 1.2 support for Microsoft SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/tls-1-2-support-microsoft-sql-server)), whereas modern OpenSSL drivers use TLS 1.2 as a minimum client protocol version.